# Обнаружение абзацев с помощью регулярного выражения при разделении абзацев пустыми строками

Tags: php, javascript, java, регулярные-выражения

Рассматривается задача обнаружения абзацев при парсинге текста. Как в полях для вопросов и ответов на этом форуме, для начала нового абзаца необходимо оставить одну пустую строку перед ним, при этом ручной перенос одной строки не приведёт к началу нового абзаца.

Нужно захватить (в захватывающие группы) абзацы. Начал с такого регулярного выражения:

```
\^(.+)$\gm
```

Оно не удовлетворяет ни одному из условий: не распознаёт пустых строк и считает абзац новым при переносе на новую строку. Основная сложность состоит в том, что перед первым абзацем и после последнего не будет пустой строки. Можно ли эту задачу решить регулярными выражениями?

Fiddle регулярных выражений: https://regex101.com/r/R13TuL/1

PS: Я привёл в тэгах те языки программирования, которыми владею. Если понадобится программное вмешательство, то можете привести пример на одном из этих языков.

Comment: Может быть напишите свою задачу, не абстрактную? Тут используется markdown. Если нужно делать markdown > html, есть соответствующие библиотеки как на PHP, так и на других языках.

Comment: @Total Pusher, моя задача состоит в разработке своего языка разметки и парсера для него, где так же, как и markdown и LaTeX абзацы отделяются пустыми строками.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(`ghj ghjg 
jk jklj klj kljklj l

jkljl jjk jl jl kl jkl


uiu ouio uo uio uio 
lklk ;lk lk ;l
klk l;

kl;k l;k l;k l;k; l





llll`.split(/(?:\r?\n){2,}/))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один из вариантов - разбить строку по двум или более символам перевода строки, полученные элементы обернуть в теги `<p></p>`, и преобразовать обработанный таким образом массив обратно в строку:

```
$str = 'К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.

Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.';


$str = join(array_map(function($str){
    return "<p>$str</p>";
}, preg_split('~((\r)?\n){2,}~', $str)));

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

`^(?:(?!^$)[\s\S])+$`

[Тест на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F3gQzC/1)